# Partial derivative of Christoffel symbols

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have faced one issue regarding the partial derivative of the Christoffel symbols. $\Gamma$'s themselves are not tensors. But if we take the difference between two $\Gamma$'s at the same point, then they behave like a tensor (the concept of torsion).

Now for the partial derivative of the $\Gamma$'s, we take the difference between two $\Gamma$'s in two different infinitesimal neighboring points, which may not transform like a tensor.

The direct procedure to check seems laborious, from the transformation property of the Christoffel symbols.
$$
\partial_{a'}\Gamma^{b'}_{{c'}{d'}}=\frac{\partial x^{m}}{\partial x^{a'}}\partial_{a'}(\frac{\partial x^{p}}{\partial x^{c'}}\frac{\partial x^{q}}{\partial x^{d'}}\frac{\partial x^{b'}}{\partial x^{r}}\Gamma^r_{pq}-\frac{\partial^2 x^{b'}}{\partial x^{p}\partial x^{q}}\frac{\partial x^{p}}{\partial x^{c'}}\frac{\partial x^{q}}{\partial x^{d'}})
$$
Where the second term will have a third order partial, which looks like a non tensorial object. SO the question is, are the $\partial\Gamma$'s actually tensorial objects?

Any hint is appreciated

Comment: But what is the question? You want a more elegant proof of your formula? As for references, I would recommend the book by Nakahara (ch. 6?) for a nice approach to this topic.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: The question still doesn't appear clear. In the last part you say 'are the $\Gamma$'s actually tensorial', for which you know the answer is no (as you yourself said in the opening).  Did you mean to ask about $\partial \Gamma$ instead?

Comment: When we take difference between two $\Gamma$'s _at the same point only then_ they behave like tensor, I presume the answer is when we differentiate $\Gamma$'s, they are non tensorial

Comment: @TanmoyPati it is still not clear what you're asking..

Comment: anyway I got my answer